# More elegant way to construct the S3 path name with given options

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I have a method that generates the S3 key prefix according to the provided args. However, my gut feeling is that this method is not as elegant as it should be, maybe I just don't have an eye for it. Care to instruct me on how to make this little bit less sketchy?

```
private String generateFullQualifiedS3KeyPrefix(DataStream dataStream, Options options) {
    String environmentName, applicationName, streamName = applicationName = environmentName = null;
    if (dataStream != null) {
        environmentName = dataStream.getEnvironmentName();
        applicationName = dataStream.getApplicationName();
        streamName = dataStream.getStreamName();
    }
    String year, month, date, groupById = date = month = year = null;
    if (options != null) {
        year = String.valueOf(options.getYear());
        month = String.format("%02d", options.getMonth());
        date = String.format("%02d", options.getDate());
        groupById = options.getGroupById();
    }

    String[] arr = new String[]{environmentName, applicationName, streamName, groupById, year, month, date};
    StringJoiner filePath = new StringJoiner("/");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == null) {
            break;
        }
        filePath.add(arr[i]);
    }
    return filePath.toString() + "/";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local variables make this very verbose:
each variable is declared, initialized, re-assigned, and referenced.
(They each appear 3-4 times in the code.)
You could instead accumulate values in a list.

Creating an array that may contain `null` values,
then filtering out the `null` values in a second step feels like a waste that's easy to avoid.
You could instead accumulate non-null values in a list.

Using `StringJoiner` is efficient to join a string from multiple parts.
Then at the end the `filePath.toString() + "/"` is an inefficient string concatenation that could have been easily avoided by appending an empty string to `filePath`.

And instead of using `StringJoiner`, you could use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-).

Consider this alternative:

```
private String generateFullQualifiedS3KeyPrefix(DataStream dataStream, Options options) {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    if (dataStream != null) {
        values.add(dataStream.getEnvironmentName());
        values.add(dataStream.getApplicationName());
        values.add(dataStream.getStreamName());
    }

    if (options != null) {
        values.add(String.valueOf(options.getYear()));
        values.add(String.format("%02d", options.getMonth()));
        values.add(String.format("%02d", options.getDate()));
        values.add(options.getGroupById());
    }

    values.add("");

    return String.join("/", values);
}
```